# Kafka client on wildfly throws Unsupported Callback Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, callback, wildfly

I have set up a Kafka cluster on my linux machine secured using keycloak (OAUTHBEARER) Mechanism. I can use the Kafka Console Consumers and Producers to send and receive messages.

I have tried to connect to Kafka from my consumers and producers deployed as module on the wildfly App server . I have set up all the required configuration (Config Section below)
The SASL_JAAS_CONFIG has the details like apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required LoginStringClaim_sub='kafka-client'

I am able to get authenticated with the broker , but in the client callback I am getting an Unsupported Callback error . I have 3 modules in wildfly

1. kafka producer consumer code dependent on the 2) oauth jar (for logincallbackhandler and login module)  dependent on the 3) kafka-client jar (2.8.0)]

I can see that the THE CLIENT CALL BACK IS CLIENTCREDENTIAL INSTEAD OF OAuthBearerTokenCallback. The saslclient is getting set as AbstractSaslClient instead of OAuthBearerSaslClient.

Can I get any pointers on this one ?

LOGS

````
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05176: Unsupported callback [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.mechanism.oauth2.OAuth2Client.getInitialResponse(OAuth2Client.java:58)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.sasl.oauth2.OAuth2SaslClient.evaluateMessage(OAuth2SaslClient.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslParticipant.evaluateMessage(AbstractSaslParticipant.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(AbstractSaslClient.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.lambda$createSaslToken$1(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:534)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:534)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslClientToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:433)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendInitialToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1261)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients@1.1.8.1//org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at com.lgc.common.core//com.lgc.dsl.notifications.consumer.DataChangeNoticeKafkaConsumer.poll(DataChangeNoticeKafkaConsumer.java:388)
    at com.lgc.common.core//com.lgc.dsds.notifications.producer.DataChangeNotificationProducer.consumeNotification(DataChangeNotificationProducer.java:204)
    at com.lgc.common.core//com.lgc.dsds.notifications.producer.DataChangeNotificationProducer.retrieveAndProcessNotificationObject(DataChangeNotificationProducer.java:106)
    at com.lgc.common.core//com.lgc.dsds.notifications.producer.DataChangeNotificationProducer.run(DataChangeNotificationProducer.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException    
    at com.lgc.common.koauth//com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler.handle(AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler.java:91)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.mechanism._private.MechanismUtil.handleCallbacks(MechanismUtil.java:156)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.11.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.mechanism.oauth2.OAuth2Client.getInitialResponse(OAuth2Client.java:56)
    ... 27 more


LOGS WHERE THE SSL HANDSHAKE IS SUCCESSFUL ,  THE CLIENT CALL BACK IS CLIENTCREDENTIAL INSTEAD OF OAuthBearerTokenCallback. The saslclient is getting set as AbstractSaslClient instead of OAuthBearerSaslClient

'''21-08-29 16:21:25,756 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Upgrading request HttpServerExchange{ GET /}
2021-08-29 16:21:25,760 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer] (OWNotificationProducer) [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=i-10-134-194-96/10.134.194.96:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@50326a63, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'i-10-134-194-96' peerPort 9093 peerPrincipal 'CN=i-10-134-194-96, OU=Foo, O=acme corp, L=Duckburg, ST=Duckburg, C=WD' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'
2021-08-29 16:21:25,765 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
2021-08-29 16:21:25,766 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2021-08-29 16:21:25,767 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | CommonKafkaProducer) [Producer clientId=CommonKafkaProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2021-08-29 16:21:25,767 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2021-08-29 16:21:25,768 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2021-08-29 16:21:25,769 INFO  [com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler] (OWNotificationProducer) The class loaders are as follows ************ Callbackclienthandler class com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler ModuleClassLoader for Module "com.lgc.common.koauth" from local module loader @6253c26 (finder: local module finder @49049a04 (roots: /opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/dv,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/base,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak))
2021-08-29 16:21:25,778 INFO  [com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler] (OWNotificationProducer) The class loaders are as follows ************ OAuthBearerTokenCallback class org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerTokenCallback ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.apache.kafka.clients" version 1.1.8.1 from local module loader @6253c26 (finder: local module finder @49049a04 (roots: /opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/dv,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/base,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak))
2021-08-29 16:21:25,787 INFO  [com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler] (OWNotificationProducer) The class loaders are as follows ************ OAuthBearerLoginModule class org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.apache.kafka.clients" version 1.1.8.1 from local module loader @6253c26 (finder: local module finder @49049a04 (roots: /opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/dv,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/base,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak))
2021-08-29 16:21:25,800 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator] (ConnectionValidator) Notifying pools, interval: 500
2021-08-29 16:21:25,800 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
2021-08-29 16:21:25,796 INFO  [com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler] (OWNotificationProducer) ******************* The callbacls are org.wildfly.security.auth.callback.CredentialCallback@2b29cf23 ClassName class org.wildfly.security.auth.callback.CredentialCallbackModuleClassLoader for Module "org.wildfly.security.elytron-private" version 1.11.4.Final from local module loader @6253c26 (finder: local module finder @49049a04 (roots: /opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/dv,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/layers/base,/opt/Landmark/DSIntegrationServer10ep.5.0/ApplicationServer/modules/system/add-ons/keycloak))
2021-08-29 16:21:25,803 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject] (ConnectionValidator) Returning for connection within frequency
2021-08-29 16:21:25,803 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
2021-08-29 16:21:25,805 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Failed authentication with i-10-134-194-96/10.134.194.96 (An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05176: Unsupported callback [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED state.)
2021-08-29 16:21:25,809 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] (OWNotificationProducer) [Consumer clientId=consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-4, groupId=OpenWorksConsumer] Node -1 disconnected.```


Config 

2021-08-29 16:21:25,119 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] (OWNotificationProducer) ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [i-10-134-194-96:9093]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-OpenWorksConsumer-2
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = OpenWorksConsumer
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 330000
    max.poll.records = 100
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = class com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.AuthOBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = class com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.OAuthAuthenticateLoginCallbackHandler
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = OAUTHBEARER
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 60000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /opt/Landmark/new_certs/securityserver.keystore
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

Regards,
Shankar
````

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time on this, so I'm leaving this for the next poor soul who runs into this.

if you add javax.security.sasl.policy.noactive to your kafka properties you can get the kafka sasl client to load instead of the wilifly one.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
...
// This property is to avoid using the wildfly sasl client
props.put("javax.security.sasl.policy.noactive", "true");
```

BTW setting javax.security.sasl.policy.noplaintext doesn't work since that is the one field that both kafka and wildfly use to not load their sasl client. I didn't try the 3rd property, but I'm assuming that on works too

**Why this works**

in org.wildfly.security.sasl.oauth2.OAuth2SaslClientFactory#getMechanismNames(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>, boolean)
https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/febc8a60e7cd34d376929e20129f0b919e2f11c1/sasl/oauth2/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/sasl/oauth2/OAuth2SaslClientFactory.java#L54

There are some if statements. If you can get that to return an empty array, then
https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/febc8a60e7cd34d376929e20129f0b919e2f11c1/sasl/oauth2/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/sasl/oauth2/OAuth2SaslClientFactory.java#L42

will return null causing the sasl client to be null https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.security.sasl/share/classes/javax/security/sasl/Sasl.java#L400 which then allow the loop of checking sasl client factories to continue and should let the kafka oauth sasl factory get choosen. (BTW I used the link for OpenJDK 11, but it works for other versions as well)

**Alternatively**

If you don't want to add an unused property you can always mess with the provider order in java.security.Security, but that sounds potentially more hazardous to me.